# GoF decorator pattern using static polymorphism (templates) in c++

Tags: c++, templates, decorator

The decorator pattern is a well known and used pattern for extending functionality of an object without affecting the functionality of other objects of the same class.
How can I use this pattern with as less inheritance involved (using templates)?

Comment: I haven't the book with me at the moment, so I cannot check, however, I may try to look at "Modern C++ Design" Alexandrescu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, the abstract interface from the polymorphic decorator becomes an implicitly defined concept and you nest the types. For example:

```
struct BasicCoffee
{
  void print() {std::cout << "Coffee!\n";}
};

template <class T>
struct CreamDecorator
{
  CreamDecorator(T x) : mNested(x) {}

  void print() {mNested.print(); std::cout << "..with cream!\n";}
  T mNested;
};

template <class T>
struct SugarDecorator
{
  SugarDecorator(T x) : mNested(x) {}

  void print() {mNested.print(); std::cout << "..with sugar!\n";}
  T mNested;
};
```

You probably want to use the [object generator idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Object_Generator) to make composition easier:

```
template <class T>
CreamDecorator<T> addCream(T x) {return CreamDecorator<T>(x);}

template <class T>
SugarDecorator<T> addSugar(T x) {return SugarDecorator<T>(x);}
```

Since you don't have a common type to store decorated objects, you need to use some kind of type inference. For example:

```
auto myCoffee = addSugar(addCream(BasicCoffee()));
myCoffee.print();
```

Alternatively, use the value you get from the object generators as an rvalue (This can be useful if you are stuck with C++03 - type erasure can also help!):

```
addSugar(addCream(BasicCoffee())).print();
```

Comment: looks pretty elegant :-)

Comment: Storing a reference instead of a copy inside a decorator fits more with what it's supposed to do, IMO.

Comment: isn't it more correct to pass the concrete object (x) in the c'tor as const reference ?

Comment: No, this way you can use both by explicitly stating whether you want a copy or a ref by instantiating the template with or without the ref. E.g.: CreamDecorator<T> vs CreamDecorator<T const&> or CreamDecorator<T&> or even using std::ref/cref and the reference_wrapper. Not using the reference allows for easier composition - and C++11 move makes this efficient too!

Comment: @ltjax ...assuming you implement the move constructor (and possibly assignment operator) :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this without explicitly wrapping all public methods of the thing you're decorating. Consider an example:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
  void foo() { cout << "Foo" << endl; }
  void bar() { cout << "Bar" << endl; }
};

template <typename T>
class FooDecorator {
public:
  explicit FooDecorator(T &t) : t(t) {}
  void foo() {
    cout << "Baz ";
    t.foo();
  }
  void bar() { t.bar(); }

private:
  T &t;
};

template <typename T>
class BarDecorator {
public:
  explicit BarDecorator(T &t) : t(t) {}
  void foo() { t.foo(); }
  void bar() {
    cout << "Baez ";
    t.bar();
  }

private:
  T &t;
};

int main() {
  Test test;
  BarDecorator<FooDecorator<Test> > bd(FooDecorator<Test>(test));

  bd.foo();
  bd.bar();
}
```

If you remove the (useless) decoration of `bar` in the decorator, compilation will fail. This complication aside, it's totally doable... except that all functions accepting the decoreable entity will now also have to be templated. So in the end I don't recommend going down this road.

Another disadvantage of this approach is that even if you only decorate references, code will have to be generated for all template specializations that you end up using, because without the vtable the compiler will have no way of treating methods of different classes with the same name uniformly; and if you make your classes inherit from a single parent which declares these methods as virtual, there is little benefit in using templates anymore - you can potentially gain performance, but you can just as well lose it because more code will bloat the cache.

Comment: can you expand your example to more than a single decorator, and wrap more than once?

Comment: @hellfire769 OK, it's really not different at all. Of course you can make another decorator which changes `foo` and chain it with `FooDecorator`, like in the other answer. The fundamental technique is the same.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid the redundant decorations (foo () in BarDecorator )? maybe CRTP can be helpful?

Comment: I don't know. The best thing I can come up with is publicly inheriting the base decorator which has all the boilerplate methods while *not* making them virtual. This way you would be able to treat decorators uniformly, assuming that you preserve their full type and all relevant functions or methods are templated.